How to Generate Map Fields in Terraform with Variable References using hclWrite in GoLang
I want to generate the following resource in go.
resource "kubernetes_secret" "vault_config_dev" {
  type     = "Opaque"
  provider = kubernetes.dev
  metadata {
    name = "vault-storage-config"
  }
  data = {
    config.hcl = data.template_file.vault_config.rendered
  }
}

Here is how I tried generating this
package hclutils

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite"
    "github.com/zclconf/go-cty/cty"
)

func generateVaultConfigSecret(clusterName string) *hclwrite.Block {
    block := hclwrite.NewBlock("resource", []string{"kubernetes_secret", "vault_config_" + clusterName})
    body := block.Body()

    body.SetAttributeValue("type", cty.StringVal("Opaque"))
    body.SetAttributeTraversal("provider", hcl.Traversal{
        hcl.TraverseRoot{
            Name: "kubernetes",
        },
        hcl.TraverseAttr{
            Name: clusterName,
        },
    })

    metadataBlock := body.AppendNewBlock("metadata", nil)
    metadataBody := metadataBlock.Body()
    metadataBody.SetAttributeValue("name", cty.StringVal("vault-storage-config"))

    dataMap := map[string]cty.Value{
        "config.hcl": cty.StringVal("data.template_file.vault_config.rendered"),
    }
    body.SetAttributeValue("data", cty.ObjectVal(dataMap))

    return block
}

However the result is as follows. There are quotes around data.template_file.vault_config.rendered.
resource "kubernetes_secret" "vault_config_dev" {
  type     = "Opaque"
  provider = kubernetes.dev
  metadata {
    name = "vault-storage-config"
  }
  data = {
    config.hcl = "data.template_file.vault_config.rendered"
  }
}

Update: 7th Sept. 2024
I managed to perform this with hclsyntax package by using tokens.
dataTokens := hclwrite.Tokens{
        {Type: hclsyntax.TokenOBrace, Bytes: []byte("{")},
        {Type: hclsyntax.TokenNewline, Bytes: []byte("\n")},
        {Type: hclsyntax.TokenStringLit, Bytes: []byte("\"" + VaultConfigFile + "\"")},
        {Type: hclsyntax.TokenEqual, Bytes: []byte(" = ")},
        {Type: hclsyntax.TokenIdent, Bytes: []byte("data.template_file.vault_config.rendered")},
        {Type: hclsyntax.TokenNewline, Bytes: []byte("\n")},
        {Type: hclsyntax.TokenCBrace, Bytes: []byte("}")},
    }
    body.SetAttributeRaw("data", dataTokens)

Is there more elegant way of doing this?

I am unsure if there is a type in go-cty for what you want here. If you want to code Terraform resources in Go then there is a TF CDK for Go.

@MatthewSchuchard from what I understood terraform CDK allows us to write tf configurations in a preferred programming language. If we wanted to ask someone else to create infra then we've to share the code. Please correct me if I am wrong.
What I wanted is to design a CLI tool to generate IaC so that end-users can run it with just a config file and create expected infrastructure.
